# doctrine odm annotations or composer autoload.php not working?

Tags: php, mongodb, yii2, doctrine, doctrine-odm

I'm trying to use Doctrine MongoDB ODM 2.0 beta on a project with the Yii2 framework, with composer version 1.8.4 and PHP 7.2, but I keep getting the error `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function add() on boolean` where the code runs `$loader->add('Documents', __DIR__);`

`bootstrap.php` file (in DIR/bootstrap.php):

```
<?php

use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Configuration;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\DocumentManager;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver;

if ( ! file_exists($file = 'C:/path/to/vendor/autoload.php')) {
    throw new RuntimeException('Install dependencies to run this script.');
}

$loader = require_once $file;
$loader->add('Documents', __DIR__);

AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader([$loader, 'loadClass']);

$config = new Configuration();
$config->setProxyDir(__DIR__ . '/Proxies');
$config->setProxyNamespace('Proxies');
$config->setHydratorDir(__DIR__ . '/Hydrators');
$config->setHydratorNamespace('Hydrators');
$config->setDefaultDB('fsa');
$config->setMetadataDriverImpl(AnnotationDriver::create(__DIR__ . '/Documents'));

$dm = DocumentManager::create(null, $config);
```

I already tried looking at [How to properly Autoload Doctrine ODM annotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14569955/how-to-properly-autoload-doctrine-odm-annotations) and [Laravel & Couchdb-ODM - The annotation "@Doctrine\ODM\CouchDB\Mapping\Annotations\Document" does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25444853/laravel-couchdb-odm-the-annotation-doctrine-odm-couchdb-mapping-annotation) and a host of other threads I can't quite recall for help, but I couldn't figure out a solution.

I also tried commenting out the lines below

```
if ( ! file_exists($file = 'C:/path/to/vendor/autoload.php')) {
    throw new RuntimeException('Install dependencies to run this script.');
}

$loader = require_once $file;
$loader->add('Documents', __DIR__);

AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader([$loader, 'loadClass']);
```

and ran `composer dump-autoload` and on command line it returned `Generated autoload files containing 544 classes`, but then I got the problem

> [Semantical Error] The annotation "@Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations\Document" in class Documents\Message does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded.

So the annotations are not auto-loading, and I have no idea how to fix that.
In the model I have:

```
<?php

namespace Documents;

use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as ODM;
use \Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations\Document;

/** @ODM\Document */
class Message
{
    /** @ODM\Id */
    private $id;

    /** @ODM\Field(type="int") */
    private $sender_id;
...
```

I also posted a thread on github at https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/issues/1976.  One commenter stated that "By default, the composer autoload file returns the autoloader in question, which seems to not be the case for you."  How can I fix that?  The only information I can find online is to put (inside `composer.json`) the lines:

```
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Class\\": "src/"
        }
    },
```

but then what class should I be loading?

I'm very confused and being pretty new to all these tools (mongodb, yii2, etc.) doesn't help at all.  I'm not sure what other information would be helpful else I would post it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try to run `composer dump-autoload` (or something like that) ? I remember having the same kind of error, and re-dump the autoload file worked. Make sure to update/install all your deps before running `composer dump-autoload`.

Comment: @Etshy  Yes, I did, but I'm still getting `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function add() on boolean` where the code runs `$loader->add('Documents', __DIR__);`

Comment: pretty weird. What's in your `C:/path/to/vendor/autoload.php` ? it should contain another `require autoload_real.php` and call a method `getLoader()`, is it there in your case ?

Comment: Yes, it contains the `autoload_real.php` file and `getLoader()`.  Looks something like: `require_once __DIR__ . '/composer/autoload_real.php';
return ComposerAutoloaderInit[longstring]::getLoader();`

Comment: yeah it seems right. weird the returned `$loader` is a bool then. Do you have a class in the file `autoload_real.php` ? in `autoload_psr4.php` do you have the `Annotation` namespace listed ? Depending your configuration it could load from `autoload_static.php` instead of `autoload_psr4.php` but usually it's `autoload_psr4.php`.

Comment: Yes...in `autoload_psr4.php` there is the line `'Doctrine\\Common\\Annotations\\' => array($vendorDir . '/doctrine/annotations/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations'),` and it's also in `autoload_static.php` as `'Doctrine\\Common\\Annotations\\' => 28,`.  How do I check my configuration?  I don't know about the class in `autoload_real.php`.  Thanks!

Comment: I saw you solved your problem on the mongodb github issue you created, so that's a reminder for you to add the answer here as well, and mark the post as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turns out that the problem (as was mentioned in https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/issues/1976) was that `autoload.php` was required twice - once in `bootstrap.php` and once in `web/index.php` (of the framework).  After the `require` line in `index.php` was removed, everything worked fine.